# how to create a pointy UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, custom-controls

I just saw local mind's app and they have a horizontal UIScrollView that has a selection with a pointy tip. How can I create such thing? I saw this often times in many apps where you don't just have a square frame, but you have a pointy edge to it, is this just a UIImage overlayed on top?

[image]

Other example would be [this](http://forrst.com/posts/Npi/original)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you disable `clipsToBounds` in the horizontal `UIView` (which is default), its subviews are allowed to stick out and draw past the edge of the frame.

Thus, yes, a `UIImageView` was probably how it was accomplished.

Comment: It's worth noting that the `clipsToBounds` property is by default set to no, so you don't need to perform anything extra to get this to work.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer: Good addition. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely achieved using an image. As simple as that.